# How to draw this graph-like structure via TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I am looking to draw the following graph-like structure via TikZ. How can I do that? I am struggling to obtain the \otimes-nodes, the \oplus-nodes, the \top-nodes, the \bot-nodes and the dotted lines.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show what you have tried so far ...

Comment: This is just a matter of `nodes` and curves between them. Nodes can be placed manually (with absolute coordinates) or relatively one to another. Then edges are to be drawn for example with Bezier curves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started. There are other ways, but this uses beginner-friendly ideas. Place nodes using the `\node` command. Then draw edges with `\draw`. There are many ways to stylize this once you get the basic idea. The easiest ways to draw curves are using `bend left` and `bend right` (optional angles), or `out=, in=` as options for `to`.

Since all the nodes have the same style, I included a `tikzset` style called `mynode`. That way you don't have to keep typing it each time and you can easily make changes.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\node[mynode](A) at (0,0){$\oplus$};
\node[mynode](B) at (-1,1){$\otimes$};
\node[mynode](C) at (-1,6){$\oplus$};
\node[mynode](D) at (0,5){$\oplus$};
\node[mynode](E) at (-.5,2){$\bot$};

\draw (A) --++(0,-1)node[right]{$(A\otimes\top)\oplus B$};
\draw (C) --++(0,1)node[right]{$A\oplus(\bot\oplus B)$};
\draw (A) to[out=180, in=-90] (B);
\draw (B) to[bend left] (C);
\draw (C) to[bend left] (D);
\draw (D) to[bend right=10] (E);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this was very helpful! I was able to work out what I needed from your answer.